# Python Change Master/Application Volume

Tags: python, windows, audio, volume

How do I change it?

I'm looking for something like:

```
SetMasterVolume(0.5)
SetAppVolume('FooBar',0.5)
```

I tried using ctypes.windll.winmm, but I can't find much documentation on how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also sorry to one man this all, but changing the app volume depends on the library you are using, if you are using pygame it is `pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(value)`

Answer (score 43):

I'd hope after 5 years this is no longer a problem for you, but I've just had to do the same thing. It's possible using the [PyCaw](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw) library.

Simple proof of concept, based on PyCaw's examples

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, ISimpleAudioVolume


def main():
    sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
    for session in sessions:
        volume = session._ctl.QueryInterface(ISimpleAudioVolume)
        if session.Process and session.Process.name() == "vlc.exe":
            print("volume.GetMasterVolume(): %s" % volume.GetMasterVolume())
            volume.SetMasterVolume(0.6, None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Even 3 years after your "new" answer this question is actual. Voted up for this and the example as well

Comment: Works for all Operating Systems?

Comment: https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/blob/develop/examples/simple_audio_volume_example.py referenced example, in case it ever changes

Comment: It worked well for me. All you need to change is `if session.Process and ...` to `if session.Process is not None and ...`

Answer (score 9):

this is a very roundabout way to do it but it works.you can simulate the key presses for the computers master volume with [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/). it works but it is quite inacurate.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
keyboard = Controller()
import time
while True:
    for i in range(10):
        keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_up)
        keyboard.release(Key.media_volume_up)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    for i in range(10):
        keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_down)
        keyboard.release(Key.media_volume_down)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    time.sleep(2)
```

this is an ok method of doing it. every keypress and release is equal to about 2 volume . hope this is somewhat helpful!

Comment: btw i know this works on windows i dont know about linux or mac though

Answer (score 3):

I ripped this from [here](https://github.com/Paradoxis/Windows-Sound-Manager) and modified it to use functions only.

```py
import time
import ctypes

# Import the SendInput object
SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

# C struct redefinitions
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)

class KeyBoardInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
        ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
        ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)
    ]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
        ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)
    ]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dx", ctypes.c_long),
        ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
        ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)
    ]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ki", KeyBoardInput),
        ("mi", MouseInput),
        ("hi", HardwareInput)
    ]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("ii", Input_I)
    ]

VK_VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD
VK_VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE
VK_VOLUME_UP = 0xAF

def key_down(keyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBoardInput(keyCode, 0x48, 0, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


def key_up(keyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBoardInput(keyCode, 0x48, 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))
    x = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_)
    SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


def key(key_code, length = 0):    
    key_down(key_code)
    time.sleep(length)
    key_up(key_code)


def volume_up():
    key(VK_VOLUME_UP)


def volume_down():
    key(VK_VOLUME_DOWN)

def set_volume(int):
    for _ in range(0, 50):
        volume_down()
    for _ in range(int / 2):
        volume_up()
```

Comment: This is a viable workaround for the EventGhost issue where the volume stops working in Win10 after installation of LAV filters.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is too late but if someone is still looking for a seamless solution

[Download this exe application from here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html)

and just call this command using python

```
./SoundVolumeView.exe /SetVolume "High Definition Audio Device\Device\Speakers" 50
```

Comment: love it. open the program manually, right click on desired device and click properties. "Command-line friendly ID" contains the name to provide as argument

Comment: But it's pre-compiled.

Answer (score 2):

```
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
 
devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(
   IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
 
# Control volume
#volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-0.0, None) #max
#volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-5.0, None) #72%
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-10.0, None) #51%
```

Answer (score 0):

So instead of editing my old answer I'm adding a new post to allow others who use self to use my old code and anyone who's not, to use my new code.

```
def get_master_volume():
    proc = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/amixer sget Master', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    amixer_stdout = proc.communicate()[0].split('\n')[4]
    proc.wait()

    find_start = amixer_stdout.find('[') + 1
    find_end = amixer_stdout.find('%]', find_start)

    return float(amixer_stdout[find_start:find_end])

def set_master_volume(volume):
    val = float(int(volume))

    proc = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/amixer sset Master ' + str(val) + '%', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks again for the reply.
I'm still getting 'The system cannot find the path specified.'

Comment: @f.rodrigues, this does not work on windows. the path `/usr` is only on unix-based systems

Comment: The question is about windows. Your answer is only for unix based systems, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyautogui`:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
x = 1

while x < 10:
    pyautogui.press('volumedown')
    x+=1
```

Comment: Nice solution! to mute one can use pyautogui.press('volumemute')

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui

x = 50
a = (x//2)
pyautogui.press('volumeup',a)

#this code will increase computer master volume by even numbers
```

Comment: Nice solution! to mute one can use pyautogui.press('volumemute')

Answer (score 0):

you can set the number of presses in pyautogui and create to an even output

e.g. 43 input = 42 output

imports used:

```
import pyautogui as p
import math, time
from tkinter import simpledialog
```

using tkinter askdialog to get an input

```
volume = simpledialog.askinteger("new volume", "what would you like the volume to be?")
```

and setting the volume

```
def set_vol(new_volume):
    p.press('volumedown', presses = 50) #sets volume to zero
    time.sleep(0.5) #using time.sleep to space the presses 
    x = math.floor(new_volume / 2) #setting the amount of presses required
    p.press('volumeup', presses = x) #setting volume
```

running the definition

```
set_vol(volume)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Ethan. I am curious to why you would want to divide the new_volume with two, and why you need the sleep?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## One liner using helper function

If not installed, run: `pip install pynput`

```
"""
You must set n to the volume levels your computer has.
x: volume in percent, 0 min, 1 max
"""
def set_volume(x):
    n = 100 # volume levels your computer has

    keyboard = Controller()
    pause = 0.0001
    desired_level = int(x*n)
    
    # go to 0 first since we dont know the current volume level
    press_count = int(n/2)
    for _ in range(press_count):
        keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_down)
        keyboard.release(Key.media_volume_down)
        time.sleep(pause)

    press_count = int(desired_level/2)
    for _ in range(press_count):
        keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_up)
        keyboard.release(Key.media_volume_up)
        time.sleep(pause)
```

Example: `set_volume(0.5)`

Answer (score -1):

First import subprocess
    `import subprocess`

Then to get the master volume

```
def get_master_volume(self):
    proc = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/amixer sget Master', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    amixer_stdout = proc.communicate()[0].split('\n')[4]
    proc.wait()

    find_start = amixer_stdout.find('[') + 1
    find_end = amixer_stdout.find('%]', find_start)

    return float(amixer_stdout[find_start:find_end])
```

And to set the Master volume

```
def set_master_volume(self, widget):
    val = self.volume
    val = float(int(val))
    proc = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/amixer sset Master ' + str(val) + '%', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

If I try 'set_master_volume(0.5,'foobar2000')' I get:
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'volume'

If I chance val to 0.5 I get:
'The system cannot find the path specified.'

I guess I need to get the application correct address, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I see no reason to set the volume to .5% as you might be able to see it will set the master volume to a percentage so say you want to change the volume to 50% `self.volume` needs to equal 50.0 so just by calling `val = float(int(val))` It will set 50 to an integer if its something like 50.1 and then changes it to a float of `50.0`

Comment: This is a Linux answer. How does it apply to MS-Windows? The question specifies Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a way to set the master volume using numpy, while still using Pycaw.

```
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
import numpy as np
```

Get the audio output device

```
devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
```

Set the desired volume in percentage (0 to 100)

```
desired_vol = 50
```

Get the volume range (min and max values in dB)

```
vol_range = volume.GetVolumeRange()
min_vol = vol_range[0]
max_vol = vol_range[1]
```

Convert the desired volume percentage to volume level in dB

```
desired_vol_db = np.interp(desired_vol, [0, 100], [min_vol, max_vol])
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(desired_vol / 100, None)
```

Print the current volume percentage

```
curr_vol = int(volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar() * 100)
print(f'Volume set to: {int(curr_vol)} %')
```