# Change master volume with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I'm a beginner on python and I want to play a youtube video with python, but i also want to put master volume to the max. I looked a lot of online programbut they didn't work. if someone could help me, it would be cool.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Change Master/Application Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828752/python-change-master-application-volume)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre]. "It didn't work" is not helpful at all in describing your problem. Please show your code and ask a _specific_ question about your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have the right libraries. For playing the Youtube video I suggest using pywhatkit

```
#pip install pywhatkit in command prompt
import pywhatkit as kit
kit.playonyt('Rolling in the deep')
```

Please read the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/) of the library to fully comprehend its uses and additional features incase you might need them. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6WV9zFJg1o) for reference in case you get stuck.

For the volume, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689521/control-volume-using-python-script) should give you an outline if not answer your question, video tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iEPzbG-xLE). ([Bonus Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCR2Weh64h4&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-lUA8uGjeXhBUUzPYc6vZRn) - to use this you will need to learn OpenCV).

Comment: FOr the sound, I tried pyalsaaudio, but when installing with 'pip install pyalsaaudio' after some seconds, there is an error, so the install is not finish and I can't use the librairy. Sorry if it's a stupid error, I don't know that much at python. And last thing, when I install the pywhatkit librairy, Visual Studio say that 'Import pywhatkit could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports). Thanks

Comment: Please provide the essential solutions within the answer, avoid mainly pointing out to an external links. These can die by time, and your answer loses its value.

Comment: Sure thing thanks for the pointer